# How to read each line in txt file which is in rar file in python

Tags: python

Now I have a task to program: read each line of a txt file which is compressed in a rar file (read directly, not extract the rar file). But I see an unusual problem:

When I print each line of the txt file, it shows only characters of each line. Here are the code:

```
import rarfile
rf = rarfile.RarFile('C:\\Users\\THELN\\Downloads\\theln.rar')
for f in rf.infolist():
    print f.filename, f.file_size
    #if f.filename == 'theln.txt':
    openf=rf.read(f)
    for line in openf:
        print line
```

Here is the result of a line (hello python):

h

e

l

l

o

p

y

t

h

o

n

I've tried to read each line directly in txt file and the code works well. Is there anyone who faces the same problem?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the line

```
for line in openf:
```

to

```
for line in openf.split("\n"):
```

Answer (score 1):

A minor adjustment in your code will get you there.

Look at the following snippet....Don't use the rarfile.RarFile class object to read. Use the filename

```
import rarfile
rf = rarfile.RarFile('C:\\Users\\THELN\\Downloads\\theln.rar')
for f in rf.infolist():
    print f.filename, f.file_size
    openf=rf.open(f.filename)
    for line in openf:
        print line.replace('\n')
```

Comment: Please let us know the details. What is not working? What is the error you get? Or what is the output? You probably needed to specify the file path of the rar file as it applies in your case. I have changed it to same path as you had in our original post. Please try again and provide us more details in support of your comment.